# MySQL Error Number: 1064 in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I wanted to create a view table in codeigniter and I'm getting the error `MySQL Error Number: 1064`

```
$this->db->query('
    CREATE VIEW totalamount AS
    SELECT column amount, user
    FROM transactions
    WHERE user = 1
');
```

Comment: can you dump the generated query please?

Comment: You should include information about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Please remember space not support of any database column like you used column name `column amount`. Now it will have `column_amount`

Please follow bellow code :

```
$this->db->query('CREATE VIEW totalamount AS
SELECT column_amount, user FROM transactions WHERE user = 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be the column you are using in select is not exist in you table.
Please verify it. Because there is space between column 'column amount'.